# Execution of multiple sql statements in airflow using execute_string

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, execute

I need to run 2 sql statements in the same session in Snowflake. So I am trying to use execute_string connector to achieve this in Airflow

My snowflake_hook.py looks like below:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
class SnowflakeHook(BaseHook):
    

    def __init__(self, sf_conn_id, warehouse=None, source=None):
        """Snowflake hook init.

        Arguments:
        sf_conn_id: Airflow connection ID providing Snowflake credential.
        warehouse: Warehouse override.  Defaults to "warehouse" key in the connection extra section.
        source: Hook source to pass to the parent class constructor.
        """
        import snowflake.connector

        super().__init__(source)
        tmp_conn = self.get_connection(sf_conn_id)
        self.user = tmp_conn.login
        self.password = tmp_conn.password
        extras = tmp_conn.extra_dejson
        self.account = extras.get("account", None)
        self.warehouse = warehouse if warehouse is not None else extras.get("warehouse", None)
        self.database = extras.get("database", None)
        self.schema = tmp_conn.schema
        self.role=extras.get("role", None)
        self.conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            account=self.account,
            warehouse=self.warehouse,
            database=self.database,
            schema=self.schema,
            role=self.role,
        )
    
    def execute(self, qry):
        """Execute a sql statement"""
        cs = self.conn.cursor()
        try:
            cs.execute(qry)
            return cs.fetchall()
        finally:
            cs.close()
```

#Added this part in snowflake_hook

```
def execute_string(self, context):
        """Executes one or more SQL statements separated by semi-colons"""
        cs = self.conn.cursor()
        try:
            cs.execute_string(context)
            return cs.fetchall()
        finally:
            cs.close()
```

My airflow dag using this to execute sql statements as below:

```
def delete(sf_conn_id):

        from custom.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook
        table_list_sql = """
                        create temporary table dim_expired  
                            as select * from expired_insert_stream; 
                        select distinct id  
                          from dim_expired
                        """
                        
        sf = SnowflakeHook(sf_conn_id)
        print(table_list_sql)
        res = sf.execute_string(table_list_sql)
```

This is failing with an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sf' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Can you show the exact error message and the line it points to.  I don't see how the current code could generate that error.

Comment: @JonSG res = sf.execute_string(table_list_sql) line throws me the error with UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sf' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you are not using the [SnowflakeOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/snowflake/modules/snowflakeoperator)?

For future reference executing several SQL statements is possible with that operator without writing a custom hook:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator

@dag(
    dag_id="snowflake_basic",
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False,
)
def snowflake_basic():

    t1 = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id="t1",
        snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn",
        sql="""create temporary table temp_table_4  
            as select * from table_2; 
            select DISTINCT(customer_id)  
            from temp_table_4;"""
    )

snowflake_basic()
```

You can also provide your statements in a SQL file. Tested with Airflow 2.5.0 and Snowflake provider 4.0.2.

Comment: Airflow version I use is 2.1.4, so I cant use this. I have to do it some other way.

Comment: I see. If you cannot upgrade to at least Airflow 2.3 you could try using the Snowflake provider version 2.7.0 (apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==2.7.0) the [SnowflakeOperator there](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/2.7.0/operators/snowflake.html) as well as hook should be compatible with Airflow 2.1.0+ and support multiple statements. In general I would recommend upgrading if you can :)
Also if you want to share, what version of the Snowflake provider did you try that didn't work?