# Airflow snowflake operator to execute multiple sql's to achieve atomicity of the transaction

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, task

In an airflow DAG , I need to execute a series of tasks .
Some_task >> Delete_data_from_table >> Load_data_into_table >> Some_other_task

The problem : If I have 4 different tasks (second and third are SnowflakeOperator tasks) , If delete task succeeds and it deletes data , Load_data_into_table task fails , We lost the data .

I am looking for a way to add (Delete_data_from_table >> Load_data_into_table) into one single transaction, so that in case of failures, it does rollback.

I know that , keeping both queries in a file , and reading the file and executing the sql's one after other would work . But I don't need that option because it does not fall in our design . Because all the queries are different and it will have dynamic values in the runtime (They are not static queries)

This does not work :
the answer recommended in this :

[Execution of multiple sql statements in airflow using execute_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75262395/execution-of-multiple-sql-statements-in-airflow-using-execute-string)

```
sql_query=
            f"""query 1;
                query 2;"""
```

This does not work :

```
sql_query= [
            f"""query 1;""",
                call stored procedure()
           ]
```

Any leads to options to achieve this problem , would be appreciated .